# Tab bar doesn't back with size after rotation

Tags: swift

Tab bar doesn't back with size after we rotate our device.

Scenario:

1. Set a root VC to first controller which is not in relation ship if a Tab Bar
2. Login to the app ( First VC might be login page )
3. Set a Tab bar as a root VC to get out of the Login VC from a stack.

Inside Tab Bar:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = self
    }
```

[image]
Screen before rotation in Portrait mode.

[image]
Screen in landscape mode.

[image]
Screen after we rotate back to Portrait from landscape.

As we can see Tab bar height is same as in Landscape position.
How could I change it ? Is there any property that will affect this ?

Answer (score 0):

As a programmer with a little code OCD myself, it bugs me that it still stays the same size in landscape but unfortunately, you cannot change the size of a `UITabBar`. You may have to look into making one yourself to be able to fully customise it yourself. Maybe disable landscape completely? It's really not necessary in the majority of apps out there today and luckily everyone's in the habit of using portrait.

EDIT:
Look into UIScrollViews. You're able to add a `UIViewController` to each page, allowing you to have that Snapchat feel when swiping through controllers and of course, you're able to create your own TabBar on top of it. I'm actually currently doing this myself. Hit me up if you want to see some code.

Comment: I have app designed as a Tab bar app.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to change it dependent on height, you can set an outlet for the tab bar, and then get the height and width of the frame.

Then run an if statement to check which is bigger, and in the brackets you can add your code accordingly, to set the height of the tab bar.

Comment: I think there should be another solution, it seems like a bug which is able to fix by setting one of the property.

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: Seting a new root VC as a Tab Bar after log in to the app creates this bug.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean now.